# Extract data from Materials Project contributed api

Tags: database, dataframe

I am trying to extract the data from [Materials Project](https://next-gen.materialsproject.org/catalysis) database, as:

```
import pandas as pd
from flatten_dict import flatten
from mpcontribs.client import Client

client = Client(apikey="MyAPIKey",
                project="open_catalyst_project")
#  print(client.available_query_params())
query = {"formula__contains": "Fe"}
fields = ["id", "identifier", "formula", "data.mpid", "data.adsorptionEnergy"]
docs = client.query_contributions(query=query, fields=fields, paginate=False)
print(docs)
for doc in docs:
  print(type(doc))
  print(doc)
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(docs)
#  print(df.head())
df.to_csv('catalyst.csv', float_format="%.3f")
```

This is getting the docs.
`print(docs)` output is:

```
{'data': [{'id': '6101e40e20c7bc66345c6d03', 'identifier': 'random698361', 'formula': 'Fe24Si24NO2', 'data': {'mpid': 'mp-871', 'adsorptionEnergy': {'display': '4.3102', 'value': 4.3102, 'error': None, 'unit': ''}}}, {'id': '6101e41220c7bc66345c6d27', 'identifier': 'random542151', 'formula': 'Zr36Fe6Sb12H2C2O', 'data': {'mpid': 'mp-12962', 'adsorptionEnergy': {'display': '-2.29104', 'value': -2.29104, 'error': None, 'unit': ''}}}, {'id': '6101e41920c7bc66345c6d6c', 'identifier': 'random1413786', 'formula': 'Hf4Al24Fe24C2O', 'data': {'mpid': 'mp-1224395', 'adsorptionEnergy': {'display': '-1.90706', 'value': -1.90706, 'error': None, 'unit': ''}}}, {'id': '6101e41d20c7bc66345c6d90', 'identifier': 'random1675430', 'formula': 'V16Fe16H6Ru32C2O', 'data': {'mpid': 'mp-980749', 'adsorptionEnergy': {'display': '-5.60641', 'value': -5.60641, 'error': None, 'unit': ''}}}, {'id': '6101e41d20c7bc66345c6d96', 'identifier': 'random1196238', 'formula': 'Ti3Fe18Ge18H2CO', 'data': {'mpid': 'mp-22130', 'adsorptionEnergy': {'display': '-1.56189', 'value': -1.56189, 'error': None, 'unit': ''}}},
```

But, I am unable to extract the values from the `docs`. I want the values `formula`, `mpid` and `adsorptionEnergy`.

For a better visualisation, I am giving the screenshot of 1st to lines of the csv file:
[image]

How I can get those values?

Comment: Thnaks for your reply. I want to unpack it as a separate column, and finally as a pd dataframe

Comment: I mean, I want in the dataframe, adsorptionEnergy as the title and only the value of it. 
error/display etc is not required.

Comment: I didnt know how to get data from a nested dict. Thanks for this,